# Простое подключение к БД Access

Tags: c#, база-данных, access, таблицы, данные

В приложении необходимо подключиться к базе данных access, в которой есть пара таблиц. По "строке" и "колонке" нужно найти значение. Не силен в теории баз данных, прошу предоставить отрывок кода, позволяющий подключиться к БД, и по двум "координатам" найти значение. Самым простым способом. Заранее спасибо

Comment: откуда вы соединяетесь и что используете?

Comment: @AzizUmarov не очень понимаю вопрос. Пишу класс только для этой цели. Применять буду в разных задачах. База данных на моем жёстком диске в файле

Comment: Ясно пишите на языке программирования? Используете студию, framework? Меня не интересует где лежит база.

Comment: Думаю тег access это продукт Microsoft Office Access. Вот прилодение вы на чем пишите?

Comment: @AzizUmarov приложение пишу в visual studio на c#

Comment: @Hellseher c# в visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте  код на подобие

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=testapp.accdb"); //  поменяйте testapp.accdb на вашу базу

OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();    
con.Open();    
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Ppoint WHERE point.X = " + X + " AND Point.Y = " + Y;    
cmd.Connection = con;    
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();        
con.Close();
```